# Mutate and Lead-lag to add the next value in a column?

Tags: r, azure

I'm having trouble adding the next date value from a column to the same row as the first date, if that makes sense. Each 'event' has a start date and an end date, both contained within a date column. I want to take the next date for a given 'event' ("Well_ID" column) and put it in the Lead_Date column so I can select data between those dates. The following doesn't give errors, but it won't populate the Lead_Date column, and I'm not sure why.

```html
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(randomForest)
library(stringr)
library(caTools)

# Map 1-based optional input ports to variables
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # class: data.frame

  dataset1 %>% group_by(Well_ID)
  
  dataset1$Lead_Date <- ""
    
  # Add a column of the next event for each Well_ID:
  dataset1 %>% mutate(Lead_Date = lead(Date, order_by = Date))
```

I'm very new to R, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you may have a misunderstanding of how the pipe operator (`%>%`) works.  For instance, the `group_by` call will not carry over to the next call.  Also, the beauty of `mutate` is that you no longer need to create a placeholder column before hand (`dataset1$Lead_Date <- ""`)

Comment: It would also be helpful if we had example data to work with.  You can add some sample data to this question by using the results from `dput`

Comment: I've realized that the group_by function isn't working in Azure ML, and that's a source of the error. I got it to work by not using mutate, which also seems to not work properly in Azure ML.